# How to fix Admin fail to login problem although registration of admin is notified as success

Tags: php

I've created 2 webpages for administrator register and login. After registration of the admin at **registrationadmin.php** page, it says the registration was successfully done. Once going to login webpage and entering correct credentials, it notifies me that username/password are incorrect. When I check with my database, details of admin registration are stored in the database of the admin table.

**What is the problem/how can I resolve this?**

---

**Loginadmin code:**

```
<?php
    require('db.php');
    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['admin_username'])){

        $admin_username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['admin_username']); 
        $admin_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$admin_username); 
        $admin_password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['admin_password']);
        $admin_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$admin_password);
        $admin_password = md5($admin_password);


        $query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE admin_username='$admin_username' and admin_password='".md5($admin_password)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($rows==1){
            $_SESSION['admin_username'] = $admin_username;
            header("Location: adminindex.php"); 
            }else{
                echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='loginadmin.php'>Login</a></div>";
                }
    }else{
?>

<div class="form">
<h3>Admin Log In</h3>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="admin_username" placeholder="User Name" required />
<input type="password" name="admin_password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to main page</a>


</div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Registrationadmin.php code:**

```
<?php
    require('db.php');

    if (isset($_REQUEST['admin_username'])){
        $admin_username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['admin_username']); // removes backslashes
        $admin_username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$admin_username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $admin_email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['admin_email']);
        $admin_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$admin_email);
        $admin_password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['admin_password']);
        $admin_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$admin_password);

        $query = "INSERT into `admin` (admin_username, admin_email, admin_password) VALUES ('$admin_username', '$admin_email','".md5($admin_password)."')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($result){
            echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='loginindex.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
    }else{
?>
<div class="form">
<h2>REGISTER AS ADMIN </h2>
<form name="registration" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="admin_username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="email" name="admin_email" placeholder="Email" required />
<input type="password" name="admin_password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>



</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: we need to see your code to be able to help you

Comment: ...for both the registration and login page

Comment: I am sorry if my way of commenting is worst as I am newbie in this stackoverflow and programming

Comment: you passing md5($admin_password) 2times may be that why it not working if not then edit your question we need to see full code with output error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your insert query (I split it to 2 rows for better readability):

```
$query = "INSERT into `admin` (admin_username, admin_email, admin_password)
          VALUES ('$admin_username', '$admin_email','".md5($admin_password)."')";
```

Instead of using **values stored in variables** `$admin_username` and `$admin_email`, you are entering just string `$admin_username` and `$admin_email`.

You must fix in same way as the password:

```
$query = "INSERT into `admin` (admin_username, admin_email, admin_password)
          VALUES ('".$admin_username."', '".$admin_email."','".md5($admin_password)."')";
```

Comment: thanks @Tatranskymedved, I will work on it based on what you share. Thanks a lot, u did help a lot.